# Linear programming of integers

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we have a linear programming problems involving two integer variables. Many textbooks state that the optimal solution will occur at the corner point. However, what if the corner point coordinate is not integer? For example its coordinate is (6.67, 10). Should we consider for x=6 and x=7 to compare which is better?